# jQuery - Add CSS3 animation to div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this loader I've created using CSS3 and CSS3 Animations. Although, I want to use jQuery to create the actual loading function (depending on how many seconds I say.)

Example, I want so I can set it to ex. 30 seconds to load the bar to full.

Currently, I have this:

```
        <div id="loader">
            <div id="bar"></div>
        </div>  
#bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 0px;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4892D9, #1960BC);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4892D9, #1960BC);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #4892D9, #1960BC);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #4892D9, #1960BC);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4892D9, #1960BC);

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 -7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 0 30px rgba(63,137,205, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 -7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 0 30px rgba(63,137,205, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000, inset 0 -7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), 0 0 30px rgba(63,137,205, 0.4);
    -webkit-animation: progress 30s linear forwards;
    -moz-animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
    -ms-animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
    animation: progress 2s linear forwards;
}
```

When the iFrame is loaded, I want to start the progress bar:

```
    $('#iframe').load(function() {

    //Code to start animation here
    });
```

As you can see, the #bar have the css3 animation set to "2s". I want to be able to change this number through jQuery. How can I do that?

Comment: Try using jQuery().animate. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: .animate wouldn't help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what purpose? It makes no sense to do so.

Anyway, you're looking for jQuery's [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
var loadingTime = 30; // Whatever time you want
$('#iframe').load(function() {
  $('#bar').css({
    '-webkit-animation' : 'progress ' + loadingTime + 's linear forwards',
    '-moz-animation' : 'progress ' + loadingTime + 's linear forwards',
    '-ms-animation' : 'progress ' + loadingTime + 's linear forwards',
    'animation' : 'progress ' + loadingTime + 's linear forwards'
  });
});
```

Untested but it should work

Comment: Thanks. This works. Well, it makes sense to do so in my script, since I have a loader made out of css / css3, and I would like to use it like I described.

Comment: Yes, but why not change the CSS directly? This approach really should only be used if a user is inputting the value for it or something to that extent